# Regex for removing text inside brackets given that opening or closing bracket can be trimmed

Tags: regex, string

Need to trim the test strings like this:

1. 'Mondraker DH **(Fourche à ch)** - Taille L' -----> 'Mondraker DH  - Taille
   L'
2. 'E-Bike 26'' WAVE **(41)**' -----> 'E-Bike 26'' WAVE '
3. 'LIV Advanced 27.5, taille **(occasion)** size **(XS)**' -----> 'LIV Advanced 27.5,
   taille  size '
4. 'Trail 4 **(29”12vit XT-625wh-CX-Purion)** **(M)**' ----->
   'Trail 4  '
5. 'Big.Nine 400 Anthracite**(black)** M-17' -----> 'Big.Nine 400
   Anthracite M-17'
6. 'Powerfly 625w **(L (29” wheel)) (L)**' -----> 'Powerfly
   625w  '
7. 'Rail Gr. M Miami Green/Nautical **(Reser. Mar**' -----> 'Rail Gr.
   M Miami Green/Nautical '
8. 'Endurance Dsic Di2 Gr. L **(Inkl. Radsatz
   17**' -----> 'Endurance Dsic Di2 Gr. L '
9. '42test **(test)** ##test' -----> '42test  ##test'
10. '**test(test)))))** test' -----> ' test'
11. 'test42 **(test(test)test**' -----> 'test42 '
12. 'test## **(test)** 42test%% **(test)** 42test' -----> 'test##  42test%%  42test'

with regex.

Requirements:

1. It is necessary to lazily capture.
2. There can be brackets inside brackets - (... (...) ...).
3. There are lines whose beginning or end is cut off, that is, there is no opening or closing bracket.

Comment: Doable with pcre: https://regex101.com/r/ADAyLW/1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching the strings, you can match the parentheses content and remove it:

```
\**\([^)\n]+(\)\**)?
```

Explanation:

- `\**`: optional combination of stars
- `\(`: open parenthesis
- `[^)\n]+`: any combination of characters other than closed parenthesis and new line
- `(\)\**)?`: optional closed parenthesis + combination of stars

Since regex match greedily by default, it will attempt to match the latest closed parenthesis possible.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/UInq0v/1).